# Multiply value selected in combobox by a number in label

Tags: c#, combobox, label, runtime-error, valueconverter

I am trying to work out how to multiply a selected value in a `ComboBox` by a string value stored in a label. I have tried converting both values to `int`s but this error keeps appearing:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedItem);
int price = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Content);
label2.Content = quantity*price;
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: You're not converting it to an int properly if the error says you're trying to cast it to `System.IConvertible`. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want the SelectedItem's Content, not the SelectedItem itself (assuming WPF):

```
Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedItem.Content);
```

But if you have set SelectedValuePath and are using some data binding to a model, you can get the selected value in an easier way (without even using convert, if the model is an integer):

```
comboBox3.SelectedValue
```

Comment: tag isn't recognised! ERROR: object' does not contain a definition for 'Tag' and no extension method 'Tag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Err, could have sworn it was tag... I'll update answer in a sec with more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite remember which exact property of `ComboBoxItem` it was (I think `Text`), but you need to get the value of its string rather than the whole object to perform the conversion. After that, just use `int`'s `ParseString` class method.